# Ubuntu/win 7 dual boot only boots to minimal grub prompt?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, wubi

I was having trouble with my ubuntu dual boot so I ran the boot repair usb and was able to boot normally once. I tried to boot again and a screen with minimal grub bash 1.99 came up. I tried the boot repair again and the same screen came up. Here is info from the boot repair. http://paste.ubuntu.com/9679354/

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Wubi install, and likely you had NTFS filesystem corruption, perhaps due to a hard shutdown? or some other crash. In any event, running `boot-repair` on Wubi installs is not a good idea... because it's not written by someone familiar with how Wubi works.

What you should do on a Wubi install is first run `chkdsk` from Windows, because the host filesystem is often what is corrupted, and only then, if necessary, `fsck` the root.disk.

But `boot-repair` will always offer to `fsck` the root.disk and this can result in a catastrophic loss. Right now it's reported a zero file size.

So, you should run `chkdsk /r` on the host *drive* and see if you have an intact `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk`. Otherwise it's probably damaged beyond repair.